# How is this polynomial related to conics?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-curves

I am currently reading Introduction to Theory of Numbers by Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery. It is a hard book to follow because the style is too terse and scattered. The author has introduced algebraic curves and intersection multiplicities. 
Some definitions as used by the author (I suspect they are pretty standard but still to clarify)

1. Set of points $(x,y)$ that satisfy $f(x,y)=0$ constitute an algebraic curve, denoted by $\mathscr{C}_f$.
2. Line $y=mx+r$ is denoted by $L$.
3. The x-coordinates of intersection of $L$ with the curve are the roots of the polynomial $p(x)=f(x,mx+r)$

The author then assumes a non-singular conic $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)$ contains rational points and the curve $\mathscr{C}_f(\mathbb R)$ contains a rational point $(x_0,y_0)$.

Let $m_0$ represent the slope of the tangent line to $\mathscr{C}_f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$. Hence, $m_0$ is rational.

For $m\ne m_0\in\mathbb{Q}$, line $L$ passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ having slope m has intersection multiplicity 1.

Now, here is the confusing part. The coefficient of $x^2$ in $p(x)$ defined above is $f(1,m)$.
$\color{red}{\text{This does not seem true}}$. What is the author trying to say?

Can anybody simplify this proof for me? What exactly is the author trying to prove in the end?
Hence, there must exist rational values $m_1, m_2$ for which $f(1,m)=0$. Otherwise the conic would not be nonsingular.

Therefore, for such $m, p(x)$ is linear and $x=x_0$ is its only root. (Why? Because the line is a tangent?)

Then, the author proceeds to state that for all rational $m\ne m_0,m_1,m_2$, the polynomial $p(x)$ has rational coordinates, is of degree 2, and has a simple root at $x_0$.

Hence, the curve must have a second rational root $x_1$. (This is pretty obvious so no worries.)

Comment: recommend you carefully go through example 8 on page 250 (I have the fifth edition)  Your $p(x)$ is (5.43) on page 251. Th paragraph with the nonsingular conic is on page 255, just before formula (5.45).

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks. So does it mean that the discussion I just pasted here is with regards to that example? I thought it was for a general non-singular conic.

Comment: Mostly, I had to go through my edition to find the pages you were talking about. This procedure is often just called stereographic projection, as we have a line going through a fixed point, then we see what happens. Since example 8 is in the plane, such a line can be determined by just one number, the slope. More commonly, as with a quadric in R^3 if you have a rational point solving $h(x,y,z) = 0, $ project by $(x,y,z) = (x_0, y_0, z_0) + t (p,q,r),$ where $p,q,r$ are integers, not all zero. Setting $h( (x_0, y_0, z_0) + t (p,q,r))$ leads to an equation for $t$ of shape $t^2 A + t B = 0,$

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for your help. I have been trying to learn this stuff on my own so I am quite disoriented. This is my first course in number theory. I believe this text is a little too advanced since I have no background in algebraic geometry. Would you suggest doing a little bit more of algebraic geometry before I get started with this? 

I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually, I suggest Weissman, good for self study: https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/  Meanwhile, there are rational solutions to $2 x^2 + 23 y^2 - 31 z^2 = 0,$ for example $(2,1,1).$ Find all rational solutions by setting $x = 2 + tu, \; y = 1 + tv, \; z = 1 + t w$  and solving for $t$ as an expression of $u,v,w$ in $$  2(2+tu)^2 + 23(1+tv)^2 - 31 (1+tw)^2 = 0$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hi, did they show the book in Denver last month?

Comment: @GerryMyerson found it, We had briefly discussed Lehman, https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/  rather than Weissman

Comment: @GerryMyerson. No. I do not have any critical reviews. Maybe I am using it wrong. I am using the book as the first step to learn Number Theory on my own. So far, I have done Real Analysis, a little bit of Modern Algebra, Probability (First Course). Coming from this background, I find the book lacking in being helpful. It could be my fault but having tried other books on Number Theory (Hardy, and Burton), I find this book rather unhelpful. A personal opinion. I am not stating it as a fact.

Comment: @PythonSage: Perhaps an even more gentle introductory book is in order… Have you already gone through something like George E. Andrews’s _Number Theory_, or  Carmichael’s classic texts?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Edited. I realize my choice of words was not the most appropriate.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan No. I have not. I have just done Burton and I found the text extremely helpful. I did linear recurrences from NZM and found it pretty comfortable. So my guess is I lack the requisite algebraic geometry background. Please share your advice. I need guidance.

Comment: You may find it helpful to peruse less terse expositions, e.g Silverman and Tate's book *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*.

Comment: Also, Franz Lemmermeyer’s paper entitled _Conics – A Poor Man's Elliptic Curve_ (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311306) is an interesting read.